# how can i customize twitter bootstrap to work with right to left language?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

**how can i customize twitter bootstrap to work with right to left language?**

*any solution is highly appreciated easy way solution or hard way solution*

Comment: Also similar question for Twitter Bootstrap 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730598/right-to-left-support-for-twitter-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 4):

you may use:

https://github.com/AbdullahDiaa/Bootstrap-RTL

or

https://github.com/donaldducky/bootstrap-rtl

good luck :)

Comment: The last two links point to the same project (one is the blog post that announces it).

Answer (score 1):

much of the twitter bootstrap framework will be reversed when changing

```
<HTML DIR="RTL">
```

I can't see any way of reversing the order of the grid columns though without changes to the view/html itself. Especially if you have more than 2 columns.

For example LTR sites will have the the main call to action on the right in a thinner column, while the content of the page would be in a wider column to the left.

If using an example layout like this...

```
.span8
  my content
.span4
  my call to action
```

You could change the span size and the alignment when rendered.

or you could just create a new view or partial/include for that section.

```
.span4
  my call to action
.span8
  my content
```

For things like the main navigation I just created a new include/partial for the RTL layout.

Comment: i use fluid layout and adding <HTML DIR="RTL"> dosnt work for me

Answer (score 1):

http://pyjamacoder.com/2012/02/01/twitter-bootstrap-v2-rtl-edition/

?
Need to use npm, but looks like it works