# Right to Left support for Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

There have been questions about this before: 
[Twitter Bootstrap CSS that support from RTL languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545594/twitter-bootstrap-css-that-support-from-rtl-languages)

But all the answers are good for Bootstrap 2.x

I'm working on a project that is in Arabic (rtl), and I need Bootstrap 3.x right to left.

Does anybody know a fix for that?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

1. I highly recommend **[bootstrap-rtl](https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl)**. It is built over Bootstrap core, and rtl support is added as it is a bootstrap theme. This would make your code more maintainable as you can always update your core bootstrap files. [CDN](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-rtl)
2. Another option to use this [stand-alone library](https://github.com/zeroxme/bootstrap-3-arabic), It also comes with few awesome Arabic fonts.

Answer (score 11):

You can find it here: [RTL Bootstrap v3.2.0](https://github.com/Kaakati/Bootstrap-Arabic).

Answer (score 8):

Bootstrap Persian version of the site http://rbootstrap.ir/ Ver.2.3.2

Answer (score 7):

in every version of bootstrap,you can do it manually

1. set rtl direction to your body
2. in bootstrap.css file, look for ".col-sm-9{float:left}" expression,change it to float:right

this do most things that you want for rtl

Comment: This was very helpful

Answer (score 6):

This is Another Project: 
[www.nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Bootstrap.RTL](http://nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Bootstrap.RTL/)

Answer (score 5):

finally, I can find a new version for the right to left bootstrap. share here for use by all:

bootstrap-3-3-7-rtl
and 
RTL Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6.1

GitHub link:

https://github.com/parsmizban/RTL-Bootstrap

thank you [parsmizban.com](https://parsmizban.com/t/bootstrap-3-3-7-rtl) for creating and share.

Comment: This one is the best!

Answer (score 3):

I found this very helpful, check it: http://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-rtl

Answer (score 3):

If you want Bootstrap 3 support for RTL and LTR on your site, you can modify CSS rules "on the fly", attached here is a function, it modifies the major classes for Bootstrap 3 like col-(xs|sm|md|lg)-(1-12), col-(xs|sm|md|lg)-push-(1-12), col-(xs|sm|md|lg)-pull-(1-12), col-(xs|sm|md|lg)-offset-(1-12), there are many more classes to be modified but i needed only those.

All you need to do is call the function `layout.setDirection('rtl')` or `layout.setDirection('ltr')` and it will change the CSS Rules for Bootstrap 3 grid system.

Should work on all browsers (IE>=9).

```
        var layout = {};
        layout.setDirection = function (direction) {
            layout.rtl = (direction === 'rtl');
            document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.direction = direction;
            var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
            var modifyRule = function (rule) {
                if (rule.style.getPropertyValue(layout.rtl ? 'left' : 'right') && rule.selectorText.match(/\.col-(xs|sm|md|lg)-push-\d\d*/)) {
                    rule.style.setProperty((layout.rtl ? 'right' : 'left'), rule.style.getPropertyValue((layout.rtl ? 'left' : 'right')));
                    rule.style.removeProperty((layout.rtl ? 'left' : 'right'));
                }
                if (rule.style.getPropertyValue(layout.rtl ? 'right' : 'left') && rule.selectorText.match(/\.col-(xs|sm|md|lg)-pull-\d\d*/)) {
                    rule.style.setProperty((layout.rtl ? 'left' : 'right'), rule.style.getPropertyValue((layout.rtl ? 'right' : 'left')));
                    rule.style.removeProperty((layout.rtl ? 'right' : 'left'));
                }
                if (rule.style.getPropertyValue(layout.rtl ? 'margin-left' : 'margin-right') && rule.selectorText.match(/\.col-(xs|sm|md|lg)-offset-\d\d*/)) {
                    rule.style.setProperty((layout.rtl ? 'margin-right' : 'margin-left'), rule.style.getPropertyValue((layout.rtl ? 'margin-left' : 'margin-right')));
                    rule.style.removeProperty((layout.rtl ? 'margin-left' : 'margin-right'));
                }
                if (rule.style.getPropertyValue('float') && rule.selectorText.match(/\.col-(xs|sm|md|lg)-\d\d*/)) {
                    rule.style.setProperty('float', (layout.rtl ? 'right' : 'left'));
                }
            };
            try {
                for (var i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i++) {
                    var rules = styleSheets[i].cssRules || styleSheets[i].rules;
                    if (rules) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < rules.length; j++) {
                            if (rules[j].type === 4) {
                                var mediaRules = rules[j].cssRules || rules[j].rules
                                for (var y = 0; y < mediaRules.length; y++) {
                                    modifyRule(mediaRules[y]);
                                }
                            }
                            if (rules[j].type === 1) {
                                modifyRule(rules[j]);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (e) {
                // Firefox might throw a SecurityError exception but it will work
                if (e.name !== 'SecurityError') {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use my project
i create bootstrap 3 rtl with sass and gulp so you can easely customize it
https://github.com/z-avanes/bootstrap3-rtl

Comment: It 'good to bring integration part of the code and not just copy a link

Answer (score 0):

We Announce the **AryaBootstrap**,

*The last version is based on bootstrap 4.3.1*

> AryaBootstrap is a bootstrap with dual layout align support and, used
> for LTR and RTL web design.

add "dir" to html, thats the only action you need to do.

Checkout the AryaBootstrap Website at:
http://abs.aryavandidad.com/

AryaBootstrap at GitHub: https://github.com/mRizvandi/AryaBootstrap