# Twitter bootstrap grid right align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, localization

I want to make an "rtl" responsive layout in twitter bootstrap, such that the right panel will go up on a small viewport.

By default the right col will go downwards on a small viewport.

Can it be achieved and how?

code sample: ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alex440/k6s4k/))

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div style="background-color: yellowgreen;width: 100%;height:400px;">
                 <h1>right-top</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div style="background-color: pink;width: 100%;height:400px;">
                 <h1>left-bottom</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730598/right-to-left-support-for-twitter-bootstrap-3) helps you with your rtl problems?

Comment: I used some other library for bootstrap rtl, but this really solves this issue! thanks!