# How to override bootstrap declarations in local.xml

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, magento, overriding

I made a single customized css file `rtl.css` to change the layout direction of my store from Left-to-Right to Right-to-Left.and have it loaded into my local.xml to override all style sheets in my store. But the this file itself is being overridden by the bootstrap.css ?
I noticed by using firebug that the attributes I modified are being inherited

How can I prevent bootstrap.css from doing this?

Comment: Refer [Right to Left support for Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730598/right-to-left-support-for-twitter-bootstrap-3).

Answer (score 0):

This is because of cascading nature of style sheets. The CSS cascade assigns a weight to each style rule. When several rules apply, the one with the greatest weight takes precedence.

> To find the value for an element/property combination, user agents
>   must apply the following sorting order:
>
> Find all declarations that apply to the element and property in
>   question, for the target media type. Declarations apply if the
>   associated selector matches the element in question and the target
>   medium matches the media list on all @media rules containing the
>   declaration and on all links on the path through which the style sheet
>   was reached. Sort according to importance (normal or important) and
>   origin (author, user, or user agent). In ascending order of
>   precedence: user agent declarations user normal declarations author
>   normal declarations author important declarations user important
>   declarations Sort rules with the same importance and origin by
>   specificity of selector: more specific selectors will override more
>   general ones. Pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes are counted as normal
>   elements and classes, respectively. Finally, sort by order specified:
>   if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the
>   latter specified wins. Declarations in imported style sheets are
>   considered to be before any declarations in the style sheet itself.

See more details [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html)

By changing css declaration order from local.xml file, you can override bootstrap.css declaration, or give high priority to your style changes.