# Bootstrap navbar left to right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

It may be stupid but I do not have any idea how to make bootstrap navbar from right to left, I'm creating an arabic website, so i want to have 'home' nav from the right .

here is my code :

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="current"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#our-menu">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

I tried *pull righ* and *dir=ltr* but it does not work
Thanks in advance .

Comment: May be this will be helpful, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9LFV5/10/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `li` are floated left by default.

Just change that to `float:right`

```
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: right
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jbjXvQ)

Answer (score 3):

There is a library for this http://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-rtl

I found this by googling "bootstrap right to left language" and it took me here
[Right to Left support for Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730598/right-to-left-support-for-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Comment: That's what I needed, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add the following CSS code inside your navbar's `ul` element.

```
ul.nav {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/fs9fafjq/

Comment: Can someone explain the down vote? my example works perfectly

Comment: It doesn't work if you use bootstrap http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/fs9fafjq/1/ so didn't meet OPs spec

Comment: I didn't down vote but the OP explained that this doesn't work (which is doesn''t with Bootstrap) - http://jsfiddle.net/fs9fafjq/2/