# What is the best way to use latest version of Bootstrap for right-to-left languages like Persian and Arabic?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, arabic, right-to-left, persian

What is the best way to use latest version of Bootstrap for right-to-left languages like Persian and Arabic?

I want a solution that does not change any parts of Bootstrap source code so if I upgraded my Bootstrap version it work fine like before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730598/right-to-left-support-for-twitter-bootstrap-3

Comment: I've never use bootstrap before for Arabic / Persian websites, however I used asp.net to generate the right to left for an Arabic / English website using Globlisation and  localisation. Each got a CSS to set the positions right to left or vice versa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right to Left support for Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730598/right-to-left-support-for-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the [Bootstrap 3 RTL Theme](https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl)

This is an easy and good solution. I tried it in one of my new projects and it works fine with all major browser. It even works well with IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

My answer here for:

bootstrap-3-3-7-rtl and RTL Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6.1

[my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44565587/5881949)