# How to RTL bootstrap 3 navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm not a front-end developer and I have this bootstrap 3.3.6 navbar. I want it to be RTL, that is: logo on the right-most corner and the menu items flow from Right to left after the logo.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top text-right" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="~/Content/Images/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Main</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Main2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Main3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Main4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>
```

I know there are quite a few similar questions on SO, and I've tried many, but none solved my issue. So appreciate your help.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730598/right-to-left-support-for-twitter-bootstrap-3