# Right to left navbar bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a right to left navbar in bootstrap at the same time when the navbar is toggled for a mobile device or a smaller screen I want the right most element to be top of my toggled navbar how can I achieve that?

Comment: Where is your code? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [so]! Please have a look at [ask] and provide a [mcve]! Right now your question is way too broad, and it rather sounds like asking for a tutorial...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right to Left support for Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730598/right-to-left-support-for-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 0):

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/
here are some examples you may try and take a look on it to make things responsive on mobile it's either you'll use css such as: width:100%; height:auto;

or use media queries